# ¿Cómo validar si existe un archivo en Python 3?

Tags: python

Me dejaron como asignación realizar un interprete de pseudocódigo a Python y debe ser escrito en python. El programa debe iniciar desplegando la terminal y esperando a que el usuario ingrese el nombre de un archivo que puede estar localizado en cualquier parte. Si en dado caso el archivo existe pues se debe realizar todo el proceso del interprete y sino mostrar un mensaje. He intentado con lo siguiente

```
def main():
    print("#>>") #se queda esperando a que se ingrese el nombre del archivo
    busqueda = input() #nombre
    print(os.path.isfile(busqueda)) 
main()
```

Siempre me regresa un False (no existe). El archivo a buscar ya probé poniéndolo en la misma carpeta que mi código escrito en python y nada. (tambien puse el import os)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Si lo que quieres es comprobar si existe dicho archivo, este mismo lo puedes almacenar en una varible y comprobar si esta contiene algún valor, si contiene querrá decir que si existe ese archvio, de lo contrario no. Es más ahi te esta devolviendo un false, con lo que quiere decir que no existe ese archivo. `if(os.path.isfile('archivo.txt)) return 'archivo existe';`

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que estas dando mal la ruta:

puede especificar la ruta completa:

```
os.path.isfile('/home/igmer/pgadmin.log')
```

[image: En mi maquina]

O indicar una ruta corta:

```
os.path.isfile('../pgadmin.log') #un directorio atras de mi proyecto
```

en tu caso seria asi ya que mencionas que tienes el archivo en tu raiz de proyecto:

```
print(os.path.isfile('./'+busqueda))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendable hoy en día es usar el módulo [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html). Con él puedes operar más seguro con las rutas sin importar el sistema operativo que uses.

Por ejemplo, para comprobar la existencia de un fichero:

```py
from pathlib import Path

ruta = Path("/home/igmer/pgadmin.log")

existe = ruta.exists()
```

Si el fichero tiene que estar en el directorio del usuario, mejor así:

```py
from pathlib import Path

ruta = Path.home() / "pgadmin.log"

existe = ruta.exists()
```

Pero tiene muchas más opciones. En la documentación tienes [equivalencias entre `pathlib` y otros módulos a los que sustituye](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module).

Muchos módulos que aceptaban objetos `file` en sus funciones, ahora también aceptan rutas `Path`.